# Is there any equivalent command for usermod?

Tags: user-account

In Linux, if I want to change a user's home directory, I can use the usermod command:

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_usermod.htm

```
usermod [-c comment] [-d home_dir [-m]]

[-e expire_date] [-f inactive_time] 
[-g initial_group] [-G group [,...]] 
[-l login_name] [-p passwd] 
[-s shell] [-u uid [-o]] [-L|-U] login
```

Is there any equivalent command in OS X?

Comment: Do you want to change your account name/home directory name?

Comment: This question has been asked before ;). Try dscl (man dscl). For examples look at:

http://superuser.com/questions/60150/is-there-a-usermod-equivalent-in-terminal-for-os-x-10-6-1

Answer (score 3):

Since my original answer got transformed in a comment due to it's brevity, here is another go.

The command that you are looking for is `dscl` on OSX (which works both in OS 10.6 and 10.7 in my experience).  As I mentioned this question has been asked before, and you can find the original answer (plus usage examples) on stackExcjange superUser forum at:

https://superuser.com/questions/60150/is-there-a-usermod-equivalent-in-terminal-for-os-x-10-6-1

which provides a number of examples for its use. For instance, adding a user to a group would work as:

```
dscl . append /Groups/the_group_you_want GroupMembership the_user
```

In addition, someone did provide a bash script that does what usermod does on linux, and you can find it here:

http://www.splode.com/~friedman/software/scripts/src/arch/noarch-apple-darwin/osx-usermod

(I haven't tested it, so it comes with no guarantees).

HTH

Comment: I'm looking for `usermod -u`, changing UID of user and migrating UID of its files. dscl can't do this.

Comment: @CharlesB have a look at this page then: http://www.inteller.net/notes/change-user-id-on-snow-leopard it's possibly more fiddly than pure `usermod -u` but as good at it seems to get